# CSS button does not highlight properly

Tags: html, css, styles, highlight

I have this button which doesn't highlight properly when I click on it, please see the  image, and CSS file down below

[image]

CSS for the toggle button:

```
.mat-button-toggle {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   height: 33px;
   width: 159px;
   border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
   border-radius: 2px;
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.mat-button-toggle:hover {
   border: 1px #000 solid !important;
   background-color: #FFF !important;
   border-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

CSS for the text

```
 .ticket {
  margin-top: 5px;;
  height: 18px;
  width: 122px;
  color: #111111;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-button-toggle-group name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style"  >
  <mat-button-toggle routerLink="ticketView" value="ticketView">
    <div class="ticket" id="p1">
      {{'TicketOverView' | translate}}
    </div>
</mat-button-toggle>
```

Comment: Please share your html, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is something else in your css html going on. I have recreated your css in codepen for you and couldn't reproduce your results. 
I would double check your html markup.
Here is the codepen I produced 
https://codepen.io/jmllr89/pen/KKdzLGw

Also you do not need !important on the :hover pseudo-class. CSS is smart enough to recognize what needs to be changed. So simply define your initial state in mat-button-toggle and then in mat-button-toggle:hover you create a second state, and css will make the necessary changes.

```
.mat-button-toggle {
 height: 33px;
 width: 159px;
 border: 1px solid #E1E1E1;
 border-radius: 2px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.mat-button-toggle:hover {
 border-color: #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, i've added the html file can you please tell me if you can see anything wrong?

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem on stackblitz using angular materials example:https://stackblitz.com/angular/vnpylokxnmd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-overview-example.css and your html/css. Is there a reason for the div inside the button?

Comment: it was just to be able to style the text, it was p before so i changed to div but i got the same problem